# Schedule a JOb on specific date in Akka Scheduler

Tags: java, akka, scheduled-tasks

I have a thread which need to run at particular day lets say it is 1st of the every month. 
As we are using Akka Scheduler from starting so i just want to know whether we can do it by Akka or not.(Quartz scheduler can solve this problem easily.)

i can see in Akka scheduler schedule function, we need to pass restart time as well in the parameter. But restart time is not same for this particular date,because some months are 30 days,31 days etc.
    So because of that my scheduler is running after each restart time passed.

```
Cron Expression: cron_expression=0 0 06 1 * ?
restart_time =86400 (here it is 24 hours)

Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(validCronExpressionTime, Duration.create(restart, TimeUnit.SECONDS), thread, Akka.system().dispatcher());
```

here validCronExpressionTime will find the valid date on the basis of cron_expression setting in file.

in akka scheduler the first arugument is just for starting the scheduler on a particular time after that it gets repeated on the basis of restart time.

Comment: did below answer helped you or not?

Comment: Hi,Amit it seems that your code will run the thread on the 1st of the month only once, but i want to run it on 1st of every month.

Comment: No, this will run on every first date of month you need to put this same code inside your actor which you want to run on every 1st date. Continue asking if any other question arise.

Comment: duration which you are setting is always checking the difference between 1st of the month to the current time, but this will not always be the case,
Schedule once will execute the runnable after the particular duration every time. here duration will be set once and every time it will keep on scheduling after that duration interval always. ??

Comment: We cannot schedule the cron like you want. We need to schedule the next event on start of every previous event. This is the only way we can do in akka schedule. If you have any problem in implementing this approach then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Create an  actor, say Test actor and tell it from your main class and inside that actor, in on receive use below code.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, <choose date of your choice>);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, <choose month of your choice>);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

long duration =(cal2.getTimeInMillis()-cal.getTimeInMillis())/1000;

ActorRef testActorRef = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Test.class));
getContext().system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(Duration.create(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS), testActorRef, messege, getContext().system().dispatcher(), null);
```

Comment: let me know if any question arise.

Comment: you set Date 1 first then added 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

I am using akka scheduler as shown in below code.

Each user can login to my Application and can create scheduler for background task.I am using Akka scheduler for this purpose.

```
public Cancellable buildScheduler(String actorName, SchedulerActorMessage message, long interval, TimeUnit timeUnit, long initialDelay, String actorMapKey) {
    ActorRef daemonRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(SchedulerActor.class), actorName);
    Cancellable cancellableActor = actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(FiniteDuration.apply(initialDelay, timeUnit),
            FiniteDuration.apply(interval, timeUnit), daemonRef, message,
            actorSystem.dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender());
    actorMap.put(actorMapKey, cancellableActor);
    return cancellableActor;
}
```

Now, in SchedulerActor I have defined job as below ,

```
public class SchedulerActor extends AbstractActor {
    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder().match(SchedulerActorMessage.class, message -> {
            CompletableFuture<String> jobResult =
                    message.getJob().scheduleJob(message.Id());
            jobResult.thenAccept(state -> {
                if (state.equals(DONE)) {
                    //do post action
                } else {
                    //handle exception
                }
            });
        }).build();
    }
```

I am passing my Job instance in the SchedulerActorMessage.